# Custom wrapper field

Tags: 8, forms

I have a normal field submit:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit,
];
```

But I wish he had a complex wrapper without using #prefix and #suffix. This wrapper also has to pass variables.
What is the easiest way to do it? Creating a tpl.

Comment: I would not advise to use `theme_wrappers` since the will be soon **deprecated**: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2714509

Comment: That issue has been open almost 6 years and is still being discussed - `#theme_wrappers` is in no danger of being deprecated "soon", and may never be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are "theme wrappers" ... this allows you to create a theme function (or tpl) to use to wrap a form element (or any element in a render array).

There is a good write-up here: https://guusvandewal.nl/drupal-blog/theme-wrappers-drupal-forms

Its for drupal 7 but not much has changed with theme wrappers in Drupal 8

Comment: Almost ok. I created the theme. But the tpl does not pass the element

'cart_cta_checkout' => [
      'render element' => 'element',
      'variables' => [
        'country' => NULL,
        'staticBlocks' => NULL,
      ]
    ]

Comment: u have any idea ?